# Stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am doing research on 4G SDN-LTE (software define network- long term evolution) using Ubuntu. First I ran `.sh` file which gave me error that the kernel newer than 3.14.x is not supported. I installed kernel 3.10, 3.13.11, 3.14. It fixed the error. Currently I'm running linux kernel 3.13.11, now it gave me the error that `stack-protector enabled but compiler is broken`.

I am building a 4G evolved packet core (EPC). The code is available on GitHub: https://github.com/networkedsystemsIITB/SDN_LTE_EPC/find/master. They used Ubuntu 14.04 for this project. Nothing else they have mentioned.

```
version 4:7.3.0 ubuntu 2.1
 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.11-031311ckt39-generic/arch/x86/Makefile:96:
```

```
stack-protector enabled but compiler support broken Makefile:604: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler

Makefile:604: *** missing separator.  Stop.

make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.11-031311ckt39-generic'

Makefile.main:70: recipe for target 'default' failed

make[3]: *** [default] Error 2

make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/shahrukh/shfiles/openvswitch-2.3.2/datapath/linux'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? Does the documentation list any system requirements? Which compiler version do you use?

Comment: i am building a 4G evolved packet core (EPC). the code is available on github https://github.com/networkedsystemsIITB/SDN_LTE_EPC/find/master. they used ubuntu 14.04 for this project. nothing else they have mentioned. version 4:7.3.0 ubuntu 2.1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information. You can delete your comment afterwards. Please also show the commands you executed to build the software, even if it's only `make`.

Comment: Bodo : Thanks very much for your comments. i installed 3.12.74  kernel and it work fine now.

Comment: This site is not only to give an answer to you personally, but also to find questions and answers for everyone else with a similar problem. That's why I suggest to [edit] your question and add the information from your first comment. You can answer the question yourself and write the information from your second comment as an answer. This might help other people who get the same error message.